# Facebook privacy policy URL: Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code

Tags: facebook, url, privacy, policy

I want to publish my first Facebook application and a Privacy Policy URL is required.

I have the page privacypolicy.html published in my website but I get the next message when I configure it in "App Details":

You must submit a valid Privacy Policy URL in order to be compliant with Facebook Platform. Request failed with error:
Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code.

The http code returned when I request the page is 200

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the access log and see what you return when Facebook does the call

Comment: Yes... it was the apache mod_security blocking facebook request.

Answer (score 15):

The URL is cached by facebook.
Adding # at the end of my Url did the job ..

Comment: I add `#` in Facebook Debug, it's working. But in source code, how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question I know, but I figured I'd post my solution and hope it helps anyone. For me I got this error because I had rewrite rules that didn't catch the URL that Facebook actually goes to in order to get the privacy policy. Facebook adds a query string to the URL that you give it for the privacy policy and since my privacy policy page doesn't do anything with the query string, I didn't check for it in my rewrite rule.

You can check out how Facebook scrapes the page you give it by going to Facebook's [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) and putting your URL in the input bar. You can also see the last time that Facebook tried to scrape that URL and tell Facebook to try again once you've fixed any issues. This will get around the caching that was mentioned in [user2390340](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390340/user2390340)'s post.

Comment: thanks for sharing https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook externalhit appears to request via the ipv6 address published in DNS if there is one available and won't check on the ipv4 published in DNS.

If your website doesn't have ipv6 enabled it'll return a 404 or 500 and you'll get that error "Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code" for your Privacy Policy URL.

Edit:
Also noted that Facebook caches the URL, I was checking it and getting a "bad response code" error even though there was no hit from their UA in the access logs.

Adding ?stuff onto the end of the URL in the Privacy Policy field bypassed a cache and the access log hits showed up with 200 OK, allowing the URL to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related to user2259887's comment about Facebook using IPV6 DNS. But after reading his comment, I was able to work around the validation issue by specifying an IP Address URL instead of using the host domain name URL.
This workaround will not work well if the site IP address is dynamic or change often.